# Arial Bold letter spacing "S" on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, fonts

I and at least one other person at work are seeing an issue with Windows Arial Bold uppercase S letter spacing.

[image: Arial Bold in Chrome and MS Word]

The image above shows the letter spacing to the left of the bold S in Chrome and MS Word. The top line shows the spacing issue, the next line shows no spacing issue.

I can't find anything online about this and am wondering if anyone else is seeing this? What could be causing this and how to fix it?

I have:
Windows 10 Pro build 19044.1415
Arial version 7.0

What information would help in troubleshooting this?

Comment: Have you spoken with your IT staff regarding this issue yet? As this is a work issue, they are the first people you need to go to.

Comment: The term is "[kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)". This is all I know, but hopefully it's a start. It may be the font is in general not enough well-kerned for your demanding eye.

Comment: This is probably related to font anti-aliasing, and is unlikely to be correctable by the user or IT.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Given that the letters used for illustration are 'S' and 'M', and unlikely to kern due to the 'M' having straight vertical sides, I'd not look toward a poorly-kerned font - especially as it doesn't appear to happen when the font size is increased slightly.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Well, assuming that "kerning adjusts the space between individual letterforms, while tracking (letter-spacing) adjusts spacing uniformly over a range of characters", it is kerning. IMO bad kerning may as well be non-zero kerning where there should be no kerning (only tracking).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - No, kerning has a very specific meaning regarding spacing between _specific_ glyph pairs (which may vary by font). As an example, setting spacing between "A" and "V" so that it 'looks right' (with the top of the V being over the bottom of the A, viz. "AV" or "VA") is what is referred to by 'kerning'. What the querent is seeing is an artifact of converting a font defined as vectors/curves into bitmaps; when the curves don't line up with the pixels of the bitmap perfectly, you'll see irregularities in the spacing at some sizes, but not at others.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - (Specifically, these artifacts are most likely to show up at small sizes, and become progressively less evident at larger sizes.)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin S and M is a specific pair…

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - "Kerning pairs" are defined individually in each font, and the kerning instructions are _not_, to the best of my knowledge, specific as to size - they are, in essence, instructions on how to alter the "bounding box" where the two characters come adjacent. When the 'M' has vertical sides (some variants have sloped sides), there can be no adjustment of its bounding box, and so kerning is not applicable.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It may be the font is not internally flawed, still *ultimately* the spacing between M and S is for some reason wrong (at least in the opinion of the OP). If it's not poor tracking then it's poor kerning. Again, maybe the kerining defined for the font is OK, but someting adds to it in the process, so *ultimately* things look wrong.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - It is inherent not in the font, but in the display driver, which must convert vector font data into bitmaps for display. The Arial family is ... not one of the best ... but it _is_ competently done by a reputable foundry (Monotype), and does not exhibit this problem at comparatively higher resolutions, even at small point sizes. No matter how well the font is hinted, at low resolution these kinds of artifacts _will_ appear.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski LOL, usually I'm the one who corrects people with the word kerning, I'm not sure I didn't use it in this post. Also, it was my designers "demanding eye" - which is their job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing here a difference in spacing between characters that is
exactly one pixel in size (bravo on having an exceptional eyesight).

Here is how your second example looks like in Word when extremely resized:

[image]

I don't believe that the problem is kerning.
I think that the problem is the fact that, finally speaking,
a pixel cannot be sub-divided - it's either totally included, or not.

In my opinion, when Windows calculates character sizes, there is a problem
when the result of the pixel calculation is not an integral number of
pixels. In this case, the font glyph generator must either round up
or round down the number of pixels that it allocates.

That is probably the reason that when the scale (pt) of the text is changed,
rounding may go up instead of down. Specifically, the space was rounded
down to 5 pixels in the upper example and rounded up to 6 pixels in
the lower example.

Comment: Actually, in the original, it's probably a sub-pixel difference. Also, your example - which isn't a bad one - uses a serif font like Times New Roman; the querent specifically asked about Arial Bold, a sans-serif font. The same thing happens, however, and will always be more visible at smaller sizes than at larger.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: You also have an excellent eyesight. True - I used non-bold Arial. As you say, the same explanation will also apply.

Comment: I guess I'm still perplexed as to why I see this on my machine but my co-worker does not. (also on Windows, same version of everything listed)

Comment: Some difference of settings causes small variations in the generated glyphs or the kerning, but I can't say which.